# Anybody knows any knowledge base open source?

Tags: open-source, knowledge-management

I want to build a web-based knowledge base system for our call center.  To save some development time, I am looking for a open source. Does anybody know any good one out there?

Answer (score 13):

How about one of the many wikis?

Kenny: I've used FlexWiki & ScrewTurn (abandoned).

someone else with RepPower to edit my post added this.
Wikipedia is powered by [MediaWiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MediaWiki).

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_wikis

Comment: Actually, I'd suggest:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_wiki_software

Comment: ScrewTurn has now been abandoned (perhaps for some time now). I've updated the answer as such. If someone knows of a branch that can be used instead, please update.

Answer (score 8):

I have used [phpMyFAQ](http://www.phpmyfaq.de/) and found it to be very good.

Comment: i too have used it and find it to be acceptable

Comment: +1 for phpMyFAQ. The only negative thing is the fact that there is no powerful code highlighting.

Comment: PMF is disappointing. Search doesn't work well at all (at least not until 2.7.5), syntax highlighter is poor and often copies unwanted newlines or other characters. Sadly I had to drop it, mainly for useless search.

Comment: I recommend http://raneto.com/

Answer (score 5):

In addition to MediaWiki that was mentioned by Kenny, you might also look at [MoinMoin](http://moinmo.in/).

Choosing between MediaWiki and MoinMoin can be a bit tough.  Here are some points to consider:

### MediaWiki

#### Pros:

- Made for wikipedia, thus is very mature and scalable.
- Fairly easy to set up.

  #### Cons:
- Made **soley** for wikipedia.  Thus it can be a bit of a pain to customize how you like it.

### MoinMoin

#### Pros:

- Very mature software.
- Huge amount of plugins and third party modules available.

  #### Cons:
- Can be a pain to install.

There are a huge amount of other wikis available, but those are the main two I would consider.

Answer (score 5):

Since I don't have enough reputation points to comment on Bruno Shine's answer, I'll add this note as a new answer.

KBPublisher 2.0 is still available on Sourceforge: http://sourceforge.net/projects/kbpublisher/

The project hasn't been updated for years. I've been running it since v1.9 or something, and it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that [phpMyFAQ](http://www.phpmyfaq.de/) is the most useful KB I have seen so far ( from open-source ).
It is simple, straight-forward KB software, is it PHP => can be easily installed on any server and can be customized if you know a bit of php. In addition it is made simple enough but with correct priorities and logic. I suggest to install it and play with it, I did and I decided to stay with this KB.

Answer (score 1):

Also, consider [GForge](http://gforge.org/).

Answer (score 1):

Based on my personal experience with this knowledge base software, I would also like to join 'Julien H.' in suggesting PHPKB from http://www.knowledgebase-script.com

Personally I believe its one of the best. Many features, continously developed, excellent support & the GUI is just simple & great.

Comment: That's not open source, is it ?

Answer (score 0):

I heard of [RTM](http://bestpractical.com/rtfm/) (The RT FAQ Manager). Never used it, however.

Answer (score 0):

Here comes another vote in favor of PHPKB knowledge base software. We came to know about PHPKB from this post on StackOverflow and bought it as recommended by Julien and Ricardo. I am glad to inform that it was a right decision. Although we had to get certain features customized according to our needs but their support team exceeded our expectations. So, I just thought of sharing the news here. We are fully satisfied with PHPKB knowledge base software.

Comment: It's not open source.